# find special exact word match and filter symbols

Tags: java, regex

I implemented this code in order to find a complete words in a sentence:

```
    @Test
    void justAnExample() {
        List<String> list = findPhrasesInDocument("adventure dream is a fun c", List.of("dre", "adve", "dream", "long program", "Adventure", "a", "c++"));

        System.out.print(String.join("\n", list));
    }

    List<String> findPhrasesInDocument(String document, List<String> phrases) {
        return phrases
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> document.toLowerCase().matches(".*\\b" + p.toLowerCase() + "\\b.*"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

The result is:

```
dream
Adventure
a
c++
```

As you can see `c++` is not correct. How I have to implement the regex expression in order to filter the word properly?

Comment: Try instead `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(p.toLowerCase())`

Comment: Can you show me complete answer please?

Comment: That *is* the answer to your current problem. Just substitute it for what you have now (keeping the rest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just split the `document` at space and filter the substrings which the array contains

```
List<String> findPhrasesInDocument(String document, List<String> phrases) {
    List<String> docList = Arrays.asList(document.toLowerCase().split("\\s+"));
    return phrases
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> docList.contains(p.toLowerCase()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Or if you want to keep the regex approach, change your pattern to something like

`"(^|\\s)"+ Pattern.quote(p.toLowerCase()) + "(\\s|$)"`

```
List<String> findPhrasesInDocument(String document, List<String> phrases) {
    return phrases
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)"+ Pattern.quote(p.toLowerCase()) + "(\\s|$)")
                                .asPredicate()
                                .test(document.toLowerCase()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't try to parse sentences by splitting on spaces. The JDK already contains a specialized class for parsing sentences (`BreakIterator`)